# MS Access Form - string from textbox used for LIKE query to filter report results

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, vba, wildcard

I have a form where the user will want to enter a partial or full string value of a project name in a textbox, hit a button in the form, and open a report that only includes projects filtered by these results.  For example, if I entered "Acc", all results in my project_name field would only include those with "Acc."

I can get this to work from a query just fine (`Like "*" & [Enter keyword] & "*"`), but I want to do this from a form. I also have a few other fields I would like to do this with too, and I don't want to have to create a new report and query for each field.  I'd rather be able to do this with VBA and a form.

My code opens the report, but there are no results.  I have even tried entering individual letters (i.e., "a") or other obviously strings with no luck. Here is my code:

```
  Private Sub Command0_Click()

  Dim stDocName1 As String, strwhere1 As String
  Dim stLinkCriteria1 As String
  stDocName1 = "Grantlist"
  strwhere1 = project_name = "Like *'" & Me![findproject] & "*'"
  DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName1, acViewReport, , strwhere1, acWindowNormal

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the right side of `strwhere1 =` one single string

Use just `Like` instead of `= Like`

Move the single quote before the `*` following `Like`

```
strwhere1 = "project_name Like '*" & Me![findproject] & "*'"
```

It would probably be useful to inspect the *WhereCondition* you're passing to `DoCmd.OpenReport`.  Use `Debug.Print` to display it in the Immediate window.  You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> to go there.

```
Debug.Print strwhere1
DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName1, acViewReport, , strwhere1, acWindowNormal
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `*` must be inside the single quotes:

```
"Like '*" & Me![findproject] & "*'"
```

also project_name must be concatenated with the statement:

```
strwhere1 = project_name & " Like '*" & Me![findproject] & "*'"
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I got an error when I tried the first one.  I also tried to bracket "project_name" but it gave me another error.  This was a tricky one, but thank you so much for responding!

Comment: Why bracket project_name? It's a variable isn't it?